# How to submit a form on a link click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a web search form which will return images and web results when they click on the link on top of the form.

So I tried to trigger the form on a link click. Example: If they click image then am trying to submit the form with the image as an option. On the link click I am able to create the hidden input, but the submit itself is not triggered.

Without hidden input I also tried the  `jQuery("#web_form").submit();`  which is not trigerring.

**HTML & FORM**

```
<span class="web"><a href="#">Web</a></span><span class="image"><a href="#">Image</a></span>

<form method="post" id="web_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">  

<input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit"/>
 <?php            
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
            {
                $option = $_POST['searchoption'];
                //perfoming statement based on option
            }
               ?>
    </form>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.web').click(function () {
  var option  = jQuery("<input type='hidden' name='searchoption'/>");
  option.val(jQuery(this).attr("class"));
  jQuery("#web_form").append(option).submit();  
  return false;
});
});
```

What is wrong in here?

NOTE: Am trying this in wordpress does that make any sense?

**EDIT** after question posted

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    jQuery('.web').click(function () {
      var option  = jQuery("<input type='hidden' name='searchoption'/>");
      option.val(jQuery(this).attr("class"));
      jQuery("#web_form").append(option).submit();  
      return false;
    });
     $( "#web_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
          alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
     });
    });
```

I tried the above to make sure whether the form is submitted or not, when i click the link i'm getting the `Handler for .submit() called.` alert message. It seems to work the submit event but it is not submitting to external url in `action` field as well `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` in action.

What is going on here? Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: looks fine... any error in your console

Comment: i dont think the click would trigger on the span, it would trigger on the link inside. what about something like this

jQuery('.web > a').click(function () {

Comment: No error in console. When i look console the hidden input field is successfully added but the form is not submitting @ArunPJohny

Comment: Click is triggering i tried with alert for that `jQuery('.web')` selector @lonewolf217

Comment: Have you considered simply using [jQuery `.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for this? The structure of the last example on the API page would help you a great deal in this instance.

Comment: I tried simply by using `jQuery("#web_form").submit()` also @ZaLiTHkA

Answer (score 1):

If you change the name of the submit input to something other than "submit" it should work (tested in Chrome):

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="mysubmit"/>
```

Comment: Thanks +1. But if change the same name to changed as `mysubmit` in php variable it is not submitting. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: The PHP code needs to be updated to refer to the new input name, in this case `$_POST['mysubmit']`.

Comment: When i update the php code to '$_POST['mysubmit']' only it is not submitting as i said in above

Comment: Sorry, the submit input may not actually be part of the POST data. But you could check for `$_POST['searchoption']` instead. To see what POST data you are actually getting in PHP, do a `print_r($_POST)`.